# How to connect from open cmis server to documentum?

Tags: documentum, opencmis

I am writing cmis server impl that connects to a documentum server for file upload and retrieval. 
 
I have the Repository Class, RepositoryManager Class, Service and serviceFactory class created. I am not sure where to provide the documentum server url and root folder details in these classes and make a connection.
Should i be giving them in the repository.properties file and read them during the service initialization? 
I am referring the **OpenCMIS Filehsare Server Implementation** code and "**CMIS and Apache Chemistry in Action book**".
 
I have connected to documentum servers through cmis client, by creating a session with the documentum url, user name and password establish a connection.
 But from server side, am not sure how to connect to.

Comment: i don't know `documentum` but did you try to use the `getSession` of `opencmis`

Answer (score 0):

Is there some specific reason why  you're writing your own implementation of CMIS for Documentum? Documentum has it's own implementation, have a look at https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-10327. I tried it and it works without a problem.